# Format MySql output

Tags: mysql

This should be simple, I'm running a query and I'm getting the output in an unreadable format:

```
 | ID      | CustomerID | ReceivedAt          | DeviceReportedTime  | Facility | Priority | FromHost | Message                                               | NTSeverity | Importance | EventSource | EventUser | EventCategory | EventID | EventBinaryData | MaxAvailable | CurrUsage | MinUsage | MaxUsage | InfoUnitID | SysLogTag    | EventLogType | GenericFileName | SystemID | 
 | 7256005 |       NULL | 2014-06-19 16:25:18 | 2014-06-19 16:15:01 |       10 |        6 | eros     |  pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root |       NULL |       NULL | NULL        | NULL      |          NULL |    NULL | NULL            |         NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |          1 | CRON[12785]: | NULL         | NULL            |     NULL |
```

This is a sample, I have more than 100k records and I need to format the output so that ever row would look like this

```
| ID      | CustomerID | ReceivedAt          | DeviceReportedTime  | Facility | Priority | FromHost | Message                                               | NTSeverity | Importance | EventSource | EventUser | EventCategory | EventID | EventBinaryData | MaxAvailable | CurrUsage | MinUsage | MaxUsage | InfoUnitID | SysLogTag    | EventLogType | GenericFileName | SystemID |   
| 7256005 |       NULL | 2014-06-19 16:25:18 | 2014-06-19 16:15:01 |       10 |        6 | eros     |  pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root |       NULL |       NULL | NULL        | NULL      |          NULL |    NULL | NULL            |         NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |          1 | CRON[12785]: | NULL         | NULL            |     NULL |
```

What command should I use?

Comment: They look the same to me :-(

Comment: It was just edited.  The OP showed unformatted data in the top example.  HTML removing concurrent spaces and messing up the column.

Comment: I edited the question, please check @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're doing some odd "raw" displaying of what the MySQL CLI gives you.  It's certainly possible to display.  Wrap that text in a `<pre>` tag.

However, a way, way better approach is to use some PHP functions to connect to MySQL directly, read the data, and display it in a `<table>`.  Search around for tutorials for using MySQL with PHP to create HTML.

Comment: I'm using command line ... and I don't have access to anything more than that

Comment: Well, your original post keeps getting edited, so i don't know what your "bad" format looks like, but it sounds like you're just printing out stuff from MySQL.  There isn't a lot of bash formatting options.

Comment: Normaly if you see this output from a console, it's correct. With a mono space font. You just have to change the console size. Or ask to open in text processing.

Answer (score 0):

try using a table and if you are using result array use (foreach loop).This way you can show the data as you like :) best of luck